# Old answer (nov 2010) shown as new

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

An answer from late 2010 has just became available in the review section as a new user’s answer to an old question.

[image]

Comment: Did you complete this review?

Comment: To be honest, I don’t remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appeared in the review queue for late answers and the user was classed as new as they only had one previous answer (which was deleted)